# Não estou entendendo a seguinte estrutura

Tags: c, ponteiro, struct

Estou com dificuldade em entender a seguinte estrutura:

```c
typedef struct TipoItem{
   int Chave;
} Item;

typedef struct TipoCelula *Apontador;   //aqui temos um apontador tipo celula.

typedef struct TipoCelula{
    Item Item;
    Apontador Prox; //      NAO ESTOU ENTENDENDO ESTA PARTE, pois apontador 
} Celula;           //      APONTADOR É UM PONTEIRO E AQUI TEMOS PROX QUE É DO TIPO 
                    //      APONTADOR?

typedef struct TipoPilha{
    Apontador Topo;
    int tam;
}Pilha;
```

Answer (score 1):

Você criou um alias chamado Apontador para o tipo

`struct TipoCelula *`

Assim, os membros de sua `struct TipoCelula` logo abaixo são na verdade:

```
struct TipoCelula {
   Item item; 
   struct TipoCelula *prox; // Ponteiro para um outra estrutura do tipo TipoCelula
}
```

Esta é uma construção típica usada em estruturas de dados como pilhas, filas, etc...

Lembre-se que o `typedef`, apesar do nome, não cria um tipo novo, ele apenas renomeia tipos ou estruturas preexistentes no intuito de facilitar a leitura do código ( às vezes até atrapalha, deixando-o mais confuso por exatamente se perder os significados quando mal utilizados ou usados em demasia).